# this reference in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Today i was writing some basic stuff of java script mean while i encountered the problem. Although i was able to sort out the problem but could not find the reason of why this were not working. Here is my code

```
$('document').ready(function() {
     $(this).click(function() {
         var node1 = $(this);
         a = node1.text();
         console.log(a);
     });
 });
```

In this in the console i see empty string. But if i change the `$(this).click(function{...})` to `$('.some_class_name').click(function{.....});` than my code works fine and display the text value of the button i clicked.
I want to know what is wrong in the above code.

Comment: You are binding the click event to the `document` .!

Comment: What makes you think `this` would magically refer to some random selector you're thinking of ?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy If you bind the document, it also getting text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must be looking for this, Use the `e.target` to get the text inside of the clicked element which is present inside the document.

```
 $('document').ready(function () {
    $(this).click(function (e) {
        var node1 = $(e.target);
        var a = node1.text();
        console.log(a);
    });
 });
```

Comment: You are polluting global scope.

Comment: @dfsq I don't understand.? how is this polluting the global scope.?

Comment: @dfsq  what is this $('document')

Comment: @dfsq OP is poluting global scope fyi. No `var` when declaring `a`, should be one of: `var a = node1.text();` or `var node1 = $(e.target), a = node1.text();`.

Comment: @zamnuts ya , now only i see that ,i changed

Answer (score -2):

Try this code
Just change the ***this*** keyword to ***body***

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('body').click(function(){
  var node1 = $(this);
  a = node1.text();
  console.log(a);
});
});
</script>
<body>

Test
</body>
```